# How to calculate a polynomial using matrix calculation with Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to calculate a polynomial using matrix calculation and not for loops.

### Theory

The equation of a polynomial of degree *k*:

> a: Coeficients of the polynomial
> t: X value
> v: Y value to calculate

[image: polynomial equation]

We can calutate all Y values for *n* X values with this matrix calculation:

[image: matrix calculation of a polynomial]

### Question

- I have all coeficients.
- I have a vector with X values using `Eigen::VectorXd::LinSpaced(size, start, stop);`

**How to generate the T matrix with Eigen?**

### Current solution

For now, I'm using two for loops:

```
std::vector<double> yVector;
Eigen::VectorXd xVector = Eigen::VectorXd::LinSpaced(40, -20, 20);

for(const double x : xVector)
{
  double y= 0;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < coeff.size(); i++)
  {
    y+= coeff[i] * pow(x, i);
  }
  yVector.push_back(y);
}
```

Comment: Do you actually need the matrix or do you need the resulting Y-values? Are the X-values always a linearly spaced interval?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't go for the more common, efficient, and numerically stable approach of ```v = ((((a[k] * t + a[k-1]) * t + a[k-2]) * t + a[k-3]) * ...  ) * t + a[0]```?

Comment: @chtz I only need the resulting Y-values. In my specific case, I only have linearly spaced interval. Why, there are faster algorithms if the spaces are linear?

Comment: @Homer512  Thanks for the advice. I didn't know there was a difference. Do you have any explanation of the difference. I codded your version like that :
```double y = coeff[coeff.size() - 1];
for(size_t i = coeff.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--)
{
  y *= x;
  y += coeff[i];
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach to evaluate polynomials would be [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Horner%27s_method&oldid=1085785315). This avoids any complex functions (such as `pow`) , is fast and numerically stable.

A version in Eigen could look something like this:

```
/** Coefficients ordered from highest to lowest */
Eigen::VectorXd evaluate_poly(
      const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& xvals,
      const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& coeffs)
{
    auto coeff = std::begin(coeffs);
    const auto last_coeff = std::end(coeffs);
    assert(coeff != last_coeff && "Empty set of polynomial coefficients");
    Eigen::VectorXd yvals =
          Eigen::VectorXd::Constant(xvals.size(), *coeff);
    for(++coeff; coeff != last_coeff; ++coeff)
        yvals = yvals.array() * xvals.array() + *coeff;
    return yvals;
}
```

[Eigen's unsupported Polynomial module](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/group__Polynomials__Module.html#gadb64ffddaa9e83634e3ab0e3fd3664f5) implements a "stabilized" version. I wasn't able to find a reference for this. In any case, if we adapt that code to your input pattern, we get this:

```
#include <cmath>
// using std::abs, std::pow
#include <iterator>
// using std::make_reverse_iterator

Eigen::VectorXd evaluate_poly(
      const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& xvals,
      const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& coeffs)
{
    assert(coeffs.size() && "Empty set of polynomial coefficients");
    return xvals.unaryExpr([&coeffs](double x) noexcept -> double {
          auto coeff = std::begin(coeffs);
          const auto last_coeff = std::end(coeffs);
          double y;
          if(! (std::abs(x) > 1.) /*NaN or range [-1, 1] */) {
              // normal Horner method
              for(y = *(coeff++); coeff != last_coeff; ++coeff)
                  y = y * x + *coeff;
              return y;
          }
          const double inv_x = 1. / x;
          auto reverse_coeff = std::make_reverse_iterator(last_coeff);
          const auto last_reverse = std::make_reverse_iterator(coeff);
          for(y = *(reverse_coeff++); reverse_coeff != last_reverse; ++reverse_coeff)
              y = y * inv_x + *reverse_coeff;
          return std::pow(x, coeffs.size() - 1) * y;
    });
}
```

Wikipedia lists [several other methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_evaluation) to evaluate polynomials.

Comment: In your second code, I don't realy anderstand why you have two diferent methods `if (std::abs(x) > 1.)`

Comment: @CharrièreMaxime I don't have a full explanation because I just took that from Eigen's source and that came without reference. My intuition says that it makes it more likely intermediate values will underflow to zero rather than overflow to infinity. That is desirable because the end result may still be finite whereas an infinite value will propagate to the end result